# docker-compose build is not working in WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have set up Ubuntu 18.04 on my windows using WSL2 and got all the installations for docker-ce and docker-compose done.I verified my installations.

```
$ sudo service docker start
```

The above command successfully starts the docker daemons but when I'm trying to build my docker image via below command,

```
{path that contains yml files}$ docker-compose build
```

It's failing with the below error.

> Service 'comp_app' failed to build: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 172.25.240.1:53: read udp 172.25.254.229:49124->172.25.240.1:53: i/o timeout

I have tried killing all my stopped containers , dangling images . Even restarted my WSL also. None seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Under WSL2, you have to use the docker-desktop running on windows, as WSL2 does not support a real init system.
To do this:

1. Install Docker desktop for windows
2. Adjust Settings for docker for windows to enable unsecured access on port 2375
3. Install docker client on WSL2 (see shell function below for Ubuntu 18.04)
4. Add "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375" in your .bashrc or .zshrc file
5. Restart your shell to pick up the new environment variable

```
function install_docker_on_linux_or_wsl2 () {
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"
    sudo apt update
    apt-cache policy docker-ce
    # Note: on WSL2, this will only install the docker client, as there is no init system
    # you need export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375 in your .bashrc or .zshrc file when running on WSL2
    # docker desktop must be running, and the option to run unsecure on port 2375 (docker options) must be selected
    sudo apt install -y docker-ce   
}
```

After this doing all docker operations e.g. docker images should work.